# How to avoid declined Outlook invitations when syncing one-way?

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, outlook

I am using Google Calendar Sync 0.9.4.1 with Sync Options of 1-way: Microsoft Outlook calendar to Google Calendar.

However, several of my invitations are not showing up. I learn that for at least one of these invitations that is not showing up, the inviter is getting spammed with decline emails repeatedly from Google Calendar, saying I declined the invitation and also saying:

```
Invitation from Google Calendar
You are receiving this email at the account xxx@MyEmployer.com because you are subscribed for invitation replies on calendar MyEmployer.
To stop receiving these notifications, please log in to https://www.google.com/calendar/ and change your notification settings for this calendar.
```

How can I stop Google calendar from spamming this person with my decline (which I did not do) and get the invitation to show up on my Google Calendar like I want it to so I can easily see the meeting I want to attend?